# How do I do a "destroy" on a HABTM relationship without it cascading to the source record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

`User has_and_belongs_to_many Marketplaces`

Join table is `marketplaces_users`.

But:

```
user.marketplaces.first.destroy
```

destroys both the join record AND the source marketplace record. I just want to destroy the join record. For some reason I can't find out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around it by first getting the `marketplace` and then saving it after destroying the HABTM relation/record. HABTM is generally for very simple use cases and you'll quickly hit issues at which point you'll want to switch over to `has_many :through`.

Comment: Please remove the code from your answer. Your first paragraph is the real answer. I've switched to has_many :through. I will accept your answer after you update.

Comment: @AKWF Made the requested changes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `delete` on the collection instead of `destroy` on the associated record.  According to the documents as I understand them, this deletes the "link" without destroying the record.  `delete` takes the association as an argument.
`user.marketplaces.delete(user.marketplaces.first)`

I've tested this, but only in Rails 4.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

See "Delete or Destroy?" and "What gets deleted."

Comment: I tried that, it actually ONLY deleted the source record.

Comment: delete will destroy only current object, while destroy will destroy current as well as dependent associations

Comment: Are you using it the way it indicates?  For example `m = user.marketplaces.first; user.marketplaces.delete(m)`

Comment: I'm using 3.2.16 still, so that explains it.

Comment: It's present in the 3.2 docs as well, so it's strange that it's not working for you. Oh well.  Looks like you have an answer.

Answer (score 0):

the only way u could do that is

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("delete from marketplaces_users where(market_place_id = #{user.marketplaces.first.id})")
```

but not sure whether this will work from inside controller or not. i have done it as seed task.

Answer (score 0):

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many

```
collection.delete(object, …)
Removes one or more objects from the collection by removing their associations from the join table. This does not destroy the objects.

collection.destroy(object, …)
Removes one or more objects from the collection by running destroy on each association in the join table, overriding any dependent option. This does not destroy the objects.
```